# save fails with controlmode="display" on form field based upon an association

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-list, edit-form

I have a sharepoint external list with an edit form containing a form field based upon an association. The field is not nullable. I want to prevent edits on the field, so I set controlmode="display". The result is that the save process fails. The form field vanishes and the form is not closed. 
This only happens with non-nullable fields based upon associations. I tried to remove the "Required"-check on the corresponding property in the operations of the external content type, but without success. Is there a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set it to New, use a default value,  and use javascript to disable the field on form load. Then utilize a PreSaveAction function to set the field to enabled and the item can be submitted to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a default value for the Field, either in the actual list columns/content types or directly in the Publishing control.